# Selecting multiindex entry using labels

Tags: python, pandas

I do not find any explanation of how to select Pandas multiindex objects by labels. Here is an example from the documentation
(http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

```
In [1]: arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
   ...:           ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
   ...: 

In [2]: tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

In [4]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

In [7]: s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)
Out[7]: 
first  second
bar    one       0.469112
       two      -0.282863
baz    one      -1.509059
       two      -1.135632
foo    one       1.212112
       two      -0.173215
qux    one       0.119209
       two      -1.044236
dtype: float64

In [5]: s.index
Out[5]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'first', u'second'])
```

We can see from this example that the multiindex contains an entry called 'labels', consisting of a sequence of 'coordinates', indicating exactly each entry of the multiindex. My questions is: How can I call an entry specifying exactly these coordinates. So for instance, what I want is something like

```
s.loc[0,0]
```

which should return 0.469112,

```
s.loc[0,1]
```

returns  -0.282863 and so on.
I cannot find this mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unstack` and `ix` or `iloc` together to achieve this.

```
s.unstack().ix[0, 0] # or s.unstack().iloc[0, 0]
```

would give `0.469112`

Comment: Ok, I see that this answers my specific question. But the problem is that in my actual problem, I have more layers of the multiindex, whereas unstack only works for one level. If Pandas provides the 'labels' explicitly in the index, should there not be a way to use it?

Comment: In that case, I could think of using `s[index.levels[0][0], index.levels[1][0]]`

I know this is might not be what you are looking for, but this is the closest I could think of.